# MeteorJS - запуск нескольких проектов/приложений одновременно

Tags: meteor

Проходился по Tutorials, строил два вриложения:
1. Родной [Todo App with Blaze](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/creating-an-app)
2. И [Todo App with Angular](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/angular/creating-an-app)

Интересно, увлекательно и ни чего сложного.
Но заметил одно не удобство - что бы посмотреть другое приложение, приходилось останавливать `meteor`, переходить в другой проект и снова запускать `meteor`.

Можно ли как то от этого избавиться и держать одновременно запущенными оба проекта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В интернете много ответов в анло-язычном сегменте, к примеру по соседству:
[How run multiple meteor servers on different ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26647063/how-run-multiple-meteor-servers-on-different-ports)

Везде твердят одно - использовать параметр `--port`:

```
meteor run --port 3030
```

Причем сам порт, как понял пишут от балды, потому что у них `так` работает.
Кто то на `4000`, кто то на `5000` предлагает запускать.
С первого раза не понятно, почему такой рандомный порт выходит и какое правило для его назначения.

> *Экспериментальным путем* было выявлено, что `Meteor` после запуска, запускает `Mongo` на следующем(+1) порту.
>   *Не смог найти в документации объяснений, если подскажите, включу в ответ.*

Причем не важно запущенно ли что там уже приложение или нет.
Свеже запущенно приложение на 2999 порту, положило дефолтное на 3000 порту.

> У @bartezr полностью не легло, но мне хватило веба

В итоге каждое последующее приложение можно стартовать *через +2 порта*, предидущее по логике *через -2 порта*.

Проверить, посмотреть что да как, можно очень просто (Mac,Linux):

```
ps|grep meteor
```

Answer (score 0):

Пользуйтесь:

```
meteor --port 3003
```

Проверил, запустив 2 приложения (одно на 3000 порту, второе на 3001).
Итог:

второе приложение не упало и возможно (требуется еще время для проверки) даже нормально выполняет запись в базу по cron, но при этом в браузере:

```
It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.
```

Номер порта выбирайте какой-угодно свободный, но главное, как вы уже правильно заметили, метеор запускает Mongo на следующем порту, т.е. разница должна быть +- 2 порта.

Comment: Почему именно `3003`?

Comment: Обновил ответ, но нужно еще время для проверки